# How do i get all author posts on custom post type list

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, filters

I am trying to filter a custom post type by some custom fields value and if the posts are by author, query for 2 custom field works but author posts doesn't work. Thanks!

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'my_admin_posts_filter' );

function my_admin_posts_filter( $wp_query ) {

if ( strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=estate_leads' ) !== false ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'level_10' )  ) {

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $author = $current_user -> ID;

         $wp_query->set(


        'meta_query', array(
        'relation' => 'OR',

    array(
       'key'       => 'leads_status',
           'value' => '-1',

        ),


          array(
               'key' => 'leads_status',
               'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
           ),

         array(

             'key' => 'author',
             'value' => $author,
         )


    ));

}
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The author key/value query won't work. 
Try modifying the query by moving the query out of the meta query like so:

```
array(
    'author' => $author,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
         array(
             'key'       => 'leads_status',
             'value' => '-1',
         ),
         array(
             'key' => 'leads_status',
             'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
         )
    )
)
```

Comment: Got error: Missing argument 2 for WP_Query::set(), called in

Comment: Here is update code works partially doesnt work the last query to get empty custom field.    $wp_query->set(

            'author', $author,
            'meta_query', array(
           'relation' => 'OR',

            array(
               'key'       => 'leads_status',
                'value' => '-1',

            ),


                array(
                    'key' => 'leads_status',

                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                ),


        ));